# If then else input file name in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I am parsing multiple files.
Is it possible to perform different operations on a relation based on the input file name.

**Below are the details :-**

**file1.txt**

**IDENT  NUM**

```
AB     1010123232

BC     1023200023
```

**file2.txt**

**IDENT  NUM**

```
ef     1010123232

gh     1023200023
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
file1.txt

AB 10101

BC 10232

file2.txt

ef  101

gh  102
```

**ABC.pig**

```
A= load '$input' using PigStorage();

B= foreach A generate ($fname=='file1' ? SUBSTRING(A.NUM,0,5) : ($fname=='file2' ? SUBSTRING(A.NUM,0,3): A.NUM);
```

But it gives error on execution

**ERROR : fname does not exist in schema**

Please advise any way to achieve this.

Comment: add the length as param and run the script X 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to extract fname using shell commands from $input variable.

**Pseudo Code :**

```
%declare fname  `use shell commands to extract filename from input`;

A = LOAD '$input' USING PigStorage();

B= FOREACH A GENERATE ($fname=='file1' ? SUBSTRING(A.NUM,0,5) : ($fname=='file2' ? SUBSTRING(A.NUM,0,3): A.NUM);
```

Comment: Can you pls share an example.  I think In the above example, the issue is the filename is looked into the schema of A and so it ignores...

Comment: @BigData : extract fname from input that you are passing using unix commands. Let me know how the input path will be ?